# On dropdown Value changes, some field will be hide and some will be newly added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newb in JS, Now I have a form there total i have 13 field, Also i have a dropdown its called **Loan purchase**

```
<label>Loan Purpose</label>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Purchase</option>
        <option value="2">Refinance</option>
    </select>
```

Now i want when anyone select **Refinance** then **3 Field have to Hide** and **one label have to rename**, and when its select to purchase then its remain same 13 field. Now what is the best options to do that.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("#state").change(function() { // foo is the id of the other select box 
              if ($(this).val() != "notinoz") { 
                  $("#foo").show(); 
              } else { 
                  $("#foo").hide(); 
              } 
         }); 
});
```

Comment: What do you currently have? What works/doesn't work?

Comment: This should be added to the question.

Comment: Sorry for that i think its not much better that code i am using so i wasn't add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `change` event and `show()/hide()` functions, check basic example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("body").on('change', "#loan_purpose", function() { 
    
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {  //Purchase case
        $("#purchase_fields").show(); 
        $("#refinance_fields").hide(); 
    }else{ //Refinance case
        $("#refinance_fields").show(); 
        $("#purchase_fields").hide(); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

```css
#refinance_fields{
   display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Loan Purpose</label>

<select class="form-control" id="loan_purpose">
  <option value="1">Purchase</option>
  <option value="2">Refinance</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div id='purchase_fields'>
    <input type="text" value='purchase_field 1'/>
    <input type="text" value='purchase_field 2'/>
    <input type="text" value='purchase_field 3'/>
</div>
  
<div id='refinance_fields'>
    <input type="text" value='refinance_field 1'/>
    <input type="text" value='refinance_field 2'/>
    <input type="text" value='refinance_field 3'/>
</div>
```